# Conditionals within ElasticsearchClusterConfig

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to conditionally import a second private subnet if a parameter (isMultiAZ) evaluates to true and if not to omit the second submit allocation using the AWS::NoValue pseudo parameter.

However, when creating the changeset I am getting the following error:

**An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template error: unresolved condition dependency IsMultiAZ in Fn::If**

```
Conditions:
    isMultiAZ: !Equals [!Ref MultiAZ, true]
```

```
VPCOptions:
        SubnetIds:
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: '${ClusterStackName}-PrivateSubnetOneID'
          - Fn::If:
            - IsMultiAZ
            - Fn::ImportValue:
                Fn::Sub: '${ClusterStackName}-PrivateSubnetTwoID'
            - Ref: AWS::NoValue
```

Am I missing something really obvious? On the surface, this seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your condition is named `isMultiAZ`, but you are trying to use `IsMultiAZ`. So it should be:

```
Conditions:
    IsMultiAZ: !Equals [!Ref MultiAZ, true]
```

Comment: Thank you :), need to work on my observational skills it seems..

Comment: @Pegasus18 No problem. Glad it worked out:-)